# Wireshark Lua dissector plugin table error

Tags: lua, wireshark

I have packet with trailer data after the packet as in ixia timestamp trailer.
I am trying to write a dissector for Wireshark that is quite the same as ixia-packet_trailer plugin. 
 https://raw.githubusercontent.com/boundary/wireshark/master/epan/dissectors/packet-ixiatrailer.c

But i wanted to write in Lua, so it is easiest to change. 
So i replace the C line

```
heur_dissector_add("eth.trailer", dissect_ixiatrailer, proto_ixiatrailer);
```

by the following in the Lua

```
eth_table = DissectorTable.get("eth.trailer")
```

But i got error from Wireshark "bad argument to get (DissectorTable_get no such dissector table)"

Comment: do you want the dissector or the the dissector table? maybe try `Dissector.get` instead of `DissectorTable.get`

Comment: @Piglet in the examples it is DissectorTable, i tried what you proposed and it give an error also No such dissector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `"eth.trailer"` is registered as a heuristic list (see [packet-eth.c](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=epan/dissectors/packet-eth.c;h=2c7b9f45f5b5ca974a9bfe7371796fafbc117c99;hb=HEAD#l927)), I think you'll probably need to follow the example provided here: https://mika-s.github.io/wireshark/lua/dissector/2018/12/30/creating-port-independent-wireshark-dissectors-in-lua.html

Basically, I think you're going to need to do something like so:

```
your_protocol:register_heuristic("eth.trailer", heuristic_checker)
```

... where `heuristic_checker` is the function that checks if the trailer is in fact for your dissector or not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Christopher Maynard I have another issue with it, i posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55450620/dissector-not-showing-tree